# Math.DivRem isn't counting how many times it's being divided correctly

Tags: c#

Whenever I do this piece of code, it's not counting correctly how many times I'm dividing it. I'm trying to calculate octal to denary number but require how many times it was divided by hence the 8.

Maybe a silly mistake or I've just completely missed the concept but I'm not too sure. Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question.

I type in 123 and its count for how many times it was divided is 2, I'm honestly quite clueless on how to solve this. Some guidance points would be much appreciated! Thanks

```
private void OctalToDen()
    {
        string input = txtInputValue.Text;
        int count = 0;

        int input32 = Convert.ToInt32(input);

        while (input32 > 7)
        {
            input32 = Math.DivRem(input32, 8, out remainder);
            count = count + 1;
        }

        string countString = Convert.ToString(count);
        rtbResultAnswer.AppendText(countString);
```

Comment: What value you are getting in `countString` currently?

Comment: I get 2 when typing in 123 as my input number, the answer should be 15 lol

Comment: And what is the logic to get 15?

Comment: 123/8 = 15 3/8? Sorry I'm not too sure what you're asking.

Comment: If you aren't interested in doing this the hard way, `rtbResultAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(txtInputValue.Text, 8);` will convert octal to base-10 (denary).

Comment: I would use that but  I need to do it this way to show the working out as how I got to the answer unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the while loop though, `count = input32 / 8;` would give you `15`. If you wan the remainder, just do `int remainder = input32 % 8;` which equals `3`... 15 * 8 + 3 = 123

Comment: Okay, I may have just overcomplicated it in my head. Works like a charm now, sorry about that. Thanks!